# ansible variable as environment variable

Tags: linux, ansible

I try  this

```
- name: Install required packages
 shell: "apt-get instal linux-headers-{{ ansible_kernel }}"
```

However getting this instead

```
{"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'ansible_kernel' is undefined\
```

I can can see this variable via

```
ansible -i myinventoryfile myhost -m setup | grep kernel
```

and also

```
ansible -i myinventoryfile myhost -m shell -a "uname -r"
```

how can I get this working ?

Answer (score 0):

Works for me.

```
% cat facts.yml
#!/usr/bin/env ansible-playbook
- name: test
  hosts: somehost.example.edu
  tasks:
  - debug: var=ansible_kernel

  - shell: "echo {{ ansible_kernel }} > /tmp/thisisverybaddonotuse"
% ./facts.yml

PLAY [test] ***

TASK [Gathering Facts] ***
ok: [somehost.example.edu]

TASK [debug] ***
ok: [somehost.example.edu] => {
    "ansible_kernel": "3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64"
}

TASK [command] ***
changed: [somehost.example.edu]

PLAY RECAP ***
somehost.example.edu  : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0

% ssh somehost.example.edu "cat /tmp/thisisverybaddonotuse"
3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64
```

Possibly you are not gathering facts, or are otherwise doing something that is unclear from the limited information in your posting.

Comment: "vagrant+ansible" on linux is the environment in which I do not have "ansible_local" provisioning.I am trying to make remote deployment.

Comment: In my custom inventory file "gather_facts: false".This is not the case.It  appears to be I forget to define "var=ansible_kernel" part in my ansible role.I add this to "vars/main.yml" it is ok now. Do I need to put this in original message at the top or leave it here.kind of new to this place